# Почему возникает ошибка Illegalstateexception getoutputstream()?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jackson, spring-jpa

Использую @Projection для того, чтобы RestController'у вернуть JSON.
Вот, сам Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "translations")
public class Translation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long translationId;

    @Column
    private String locale;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "messagekey", length = 3000)
    private String key;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "messagecontent", length = 100000)
    private String content;

    public Translation() {}

}
```

Вот, проекция этой сущности:

```
public interface TranslationProjection {

    @JsonIgnore
    String getMessagekey();

    Long getId_Ru();

    Long getId_En();

    @JsonIgnore
    String getContent_Ru();

    @JsonIgnore
    String getContent_En();
}
```

Вот, метод в Repository, который возвращает проекцию:

```
@Repository
public interface TranslationRepository extends JpaRepository<Translation, Long> {

@Query(value =
        "SELECT \"messagekey\", " +
                "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='ru') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_ru, " +
                "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='en') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_en, " +
                "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='ru') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_ru, " +
                "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='en') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_en " +
                "FROM \"translations\" GROUP BY \"messagekey\";", nativeQuery = true)
List<TranslationProjection> getAllTranslationsWithLocaleAndId();

}
```

Сам SQL запрос не содержит ошибки и корректно выполняется в консоли.

SQL запрос (MySQL, H2)

```
SELECT "messagekey",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ("locale"='ru') THEN "messagecontent" ELSE null END ) AS content_ru,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ("locale"='en') THEN "messagecontent" ELSE null END ) AS content_en,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ("locale"='ru') THEN "translation_id" ELSE null END ) AS id_ru,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ("locale"='en') THEN "translation_id" ELSE null END ) AS id_en
FROM "translations" GROUP BY "messagekey";
```

Результат (скрин):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема - При обращении к контроллеру появляется исключение:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/ajax/translations")
public class BackendAjaxTranslationController {

    @Autowired
    private TranslationRepository translationRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<TranslationProjection> getAllTranslations() {
        return translationRepository.getAllTranslationsWithLocaleAndId();
    }
}
```

Исключение - java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:581) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:155) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:155) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:360) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.j

ava:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Чтобы избежать этого исключения к строковым значениям проекции TranslationProjection добавил аннотацию @JsonIgnore. 
Ошибка возникает, если строковые значения не имеют этой аннотации, а если игнорировать эти String, то ошибки нет.

Результат:

```
[{"id_Ru":687,"id_En":688},{"id_Ru":943,"id_En":944}]
```

Я знаю, что обычно такая проблема вознимает при использовании @OneToMany & @ManyToOne. 
Но в данном случае ни сама сущность, ни ее проекция не ссылаются на объект. В чем может быть проблема?
Также пробовал в SQL поставить LIMIT 10, все равно не помогло...

Буду рад совету и профессиональной помощи) Заранее благодарен!

**Обновлено!**
Попробовал запустить этот же код на чистом проекте без шаблонизатора thymeleaf, как мне было посоветовано.
Ситуация та же, хоть и лог исключения отличается. Значения с типом Long выводит, а вот,  с типом String не хочет выводить.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Projection type must be an interface!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Projection type must be an interface! (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113["content_Az"])
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:296)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:295)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

Comment: Кажется, проблема может быть в либе для отрисовки (или чем там занимается ThymeleafView). Судя по исходникам оной, проблему можно обойти, если подменить значение переменной `AbstractThymeleafView.producePartialOutputWhileProcessing` на `false`. Но вот как это сделать - не подскажу. Скорее всего надо рыться в исходниках и искать где и в каком месте можно подсунуть спрингу собственную реализацию `ThymeleafView` у которой будет вызван сеттер для переменной.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А как Thymeleaf связана с этим делом, ведь вроде бы я возвращаю json... Я не уверен конечно) Хотя, для чистоты эксперимента постарался вывести данные в шаблоне thymeleaf через th:each и также на значениях типа String падает, а Long выводит нормально. Попробую покопаться дальше)

Comment: Ну, я просто вижу в логах, что используется этот класс и там внутри действительно идёт попытка использовать то, что падает. Отсюда и делаю вывод, что проблема тут. Попробуйте убрать вообще зависимость Thymeleaf  из проекта - по идее должно заработать. Если это сложно в живом проекте сделать - можно с нуля пустой проект сделать чисто для теста.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую на чистом проекте. А вот, отключение spring.thymeleaf.servlet.produce-partial-output-while-processing = false  не дало результатов. Нашел вот, тут, как можно отключить: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Configuration-Changelog

Comment: Только, что попробовал на чистом проекте без шаблонизатора. Обновил вопрос (см. "Обновлено"). ситуация та же, только лог ошибок отличается. Также на Long работает нормально, а на String падает.

Comment: Вот, теперь ошибка нормальная стала) Думаю, проблема в порядке объявления методов в интерфейсе. Попробуйте сделать так, чтобы методы шли в том же порядке что и колонки в запросе к БД. Ну и надо проверить их имена на всякий случай и тип данных в колонках в БД (вдруг где-то число, а не строка)

Comment: Тоже наткнулся на то, что порядок методов интерфейса должен быть соблюден согласно SQL запросу. С этим тоже была проблема, но кажется проблема в типах данных в колонках... В общем, для сущности Translation использую @ Lob из-за чего для String вместо VARCHAR создается CLOB. Отсюда и ошибка. Если убрать @ Lob, то тип создается VARCHAR и все работает.

Comment: Отлично) Остался один вопрос - с Thymeleaf действительно нет нужного сообщения об ошибке в логах? Или оно просто спрятано глубже?

Comment: Thymeleaf не ругается. Даже постарался добавить breakpoint для IllegalStateException и все равно все ок. Видимо, проблема все-таки была изначально в этом, но почему-то шаблонизатор "реагировал" быстрее...  и соответственно, мы не видели полной картины ошибки) Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря подсказке профессиональных коллег удалось устранить эту причину)
Причина заключалась в том, что:
1) Порядок методов в интерфейсе и соответственно, порядок SQL statements должен быть соблюден.

```
public interface TranslationProjection {

    String getMessagekey();

    String getContent_Ru();  // <-- перекинул вверх

    String getContent_En();   // <-- перекинул вверх

    Long getId_Ru();

    Long getId_En();

}
```

Сам SQL запрос:

```
@Query(value =
"SELECT \"messagekey\"," +
        "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='ru') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_ru," +
        "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='en') THEN \"messagecontent\" ELSE null END ) AS content_en," +
        "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='ru') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_ru," +
        "MAX(CASE WHEN (\"locale\"='en') THEN \"translation_id\" ELSE null END ) AS id_en " +
        "FROM \"translations\" GROUP BY \"messagekey\";", nativeQuery = true)
List<TranslationProjection> getAllTranslationsWithLocaleAndId();
```

Другая проблема в тип хранимых данных в БД.

Если вы помечаете примитивы сущности String аннотацией @ Lob, то в БД хранится в виде CLOB вместо VARCHAR.
Если убрать @ Lob, то соответственно в БД тип VARCHAR и все работает, как надо.